# What is the error in my php code that I cannot use the edit(function)?

Tags: php, mysql

I have sql consist of: idChecklist,descriptiveTitle, courseNo, lec, lab, units, year, semester. Now there is no error in my code when I run, but I cannot edit the words I want to edit. It just views my data in database. when I click the edit and press save nothing happens. **What is the missed for edit in my code?** Thanks

> editSubject.php

```
 <?php
include 'connection.php';

$id=$_GET['id'];

?>
<html>
<title>Edit Subjects</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
<table>
<?php $checklist_query=mysql_query("select * from checklist where idChecklist='$id'");
$checklist_rows=mysql_fetch_array($checklist_query);
?>
<tr><td>Course:</td><td><input type="text" name="course" value="<?php echo $checklist_rows['course'];  ?>"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Descriptive Title:</td><td><input type="text" name="descriptiveTitle" value="<?php echo $checklist_rows['descriptiveTitle'];  ?>"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Course No:</td><td><input type="text" name="courseNo" value="<?php echo $checklist_rows['courseNo'];  ?>"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Lec:</td><td><input type="text" name="lec" value="<?php echo $checklist_rows['lec']; ?>" ></td></tr>
<tr><td>Lab:</td><td><input type="text" name="lab" value="<?php echo $checklist_rows['lab']; ?>" ></td></tr>
<tr><td>Units:</td><td><input type="text" name="units" value="<?php echo $checklist_rows['units']; ?>" ></td></tr>
<tr><td>Year:</td><td><input type="text" name="year" value="<?php echo $checklist_rows['year']; ?>" ></td></tr>
<tr><td>Semester:</td><td><input type="text" name="semester" value="<?php echo $checklist_rows['semester']; ?>" ></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="save"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

$course=$_POST['course'];
$descriptiveTitle=$_POST['descriptiveTitle'];
$courseNo=$_POST['courseNo'];
$lec=$_POST['lec'];
$lab=$_POST['lab'];
$units=$_POST['units'];
$year=$_POST['year'];
$semester=$_POST['semester'];
mysql_query("update subjectschedule set course='$course',descriptiveTitle='$descriptiveTitle',courseNo='$courseNo',lec='$lec' ,lab='$lab' ,units='$units' ,year='$year' ,semester='$semester'where idChecklist='$id'");
header('location:checklist.php');

}
?>
```

> Checklist.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<body>
<a href="index.php">Back</a>
<a href="addSubject.php">AddSubject</a>

<p>Sort by:</p>
    Course<select id = "course">
    <option value="">----</option>
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
    require "connection.php";
    $sql="Select course from checklist group by course;";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo    '<option value="'.$row["course"].'">'.$row["course"].'</option>';
        }
     ?>
     </select>
     Year<select id = "year">
    <option value="">----</option>
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
    require "connection.php";
    $sql="select year from checklist group by year;";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo    '<option value="'.$row["year"].'">'.$row["year"].'</option>';
        }
     ?>
    </select>
    Semester<select id = "semester">
    <option value="">----</option>
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
    require "connection.php";
    $sql="Select semester from checklist group by semester;";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo    '<option value="'.$row["semester"].'">'.$row["semester"].'</option>';
        }
     ?>
     </select>
     <table border="1">
     <?php
    $checklist_query=mysql_query("select * from checklist");
    while($checklist_rows=mysql_fetch_array($checklist_query)){
        ?>
    <tr>
<td><?php echo $checklist_rows['course'] ; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $checklist_rows['descriptiveTitle'] ; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $checklist_rows['courseNo'] ; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $checklist_rows['lec'] ; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $checklist_rows['lab'] ; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $checklist_rows['units'] ; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $checklist_rows['year'] ; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $checklist_rows['semester'] ; ?></td>
<td><a href="viewSubjectSchedule.php<?php echo '?id=' .$checklist_rows['idChecklist']; ?>">Schedule/s</a></td>
<td><a href="editSubject.php<?php echo '?id='.$checklist_rows['idChecklist']; ?>">Edit</a></td>
<td><a href="deleteSubject.php<?php echo '?id='.$checklist_rows['idChecklist']; ?>">Delete</a></td>

</tr>
<?php }?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you only issue is DB is not saving the values correct?

Comment: can you be more specific thanks :)

Comment: you're calling header() after you are outputting some text/HTML to the browser, which is a no-no.

Comment: I get it now :)  mysql_query("update checklist set course='$course',descriptiveTitle='$descriptiveTitle',courseNo='$courseNo',lec='$lec' ,lab='$lab' ,units='$units' ,year='$year' ,semester='$semester' where idChecklist='$id'");
 is the answer I have different name in editSubject.php

Answer (score 0):

you're calling header() after you are outputting some text/HTML to the browser, which is a no-no. so you must put this block at top of your codes.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
  ...
}
```

and there are two duplicates for 'require "connection.php";' in checklist.php

in update query there is no space before where! you need to seperate words with space.
semester='$semester'where

you should use mysql_real_scape_string() to prevent sql injection. ex:

```
$semester = mysql_real_scape_string($_POST['semester']);
```

or when you know it's integer:

```
$id = (int) $_GET['id'];
```

It's a good practise to use mysqli or PDO instead of mysql, because it's deprecated.